# KeyError: 'my.object' Ok [Odoo/Openerp]

Tags: python, odoo

I created a custom module, I want to create new object but whenever I install it in Odoo, it always returns KeyError.

**py.file**

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm

class my_object(orm.TransientModel):
    _inherit = 'my.object'

    _columns = {
            'relation': fields.char('Relation')
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`_inherit` is used for *inheriting* existing models, not creating new models. If `my.object` doesn't yet exist and you want to create it you should use `_name` instead of `_inherit`:

```
from openerp.osv import fields, orm

class my_object(orm.TransientModel):
    _name = 'my.object'

    _columns = {
            'relation': fields.char('Relation')
            }
```

or using the current Odoo API (the one you use is deprecated):

```
from openerp import models, fields

class MyClass(models.TransientModel):
    _name = 'my.object'

    relation = fields.Char()
```

Comment: I just realized it a while ago after posting before I saw your post. Lol But still thanks for this! :)